# Как получить текущий цвет окна Windows 10?

Tags: python-3.x, windows, qt, pyqt5, winapi

Всем привет!
Подскажите, как получить цвет рамки окна, который автоматически изменяется при смене темы?

Вроде нашел функцию на C++ : `GetSysColor(COLOR_WINDOWFRAME)` [(описание функции на microsoft.com)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371(v=vs.85).aspx)
, но не получается скрестить с Python 3.6 и PyQt5

Хочу сделать динамический фон кнопок с градиентом на основе цвета рамки в моем небольшом приложении:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[Ссылка на приложение (github)](https://github.com/samwl/daily_bing_wallpapper)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне подумалось, а что если сделать скриншот окна и вытащить цвет из заголовка.

---

```
from PyQt5 import Qt


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    # NOTE: для отладки
    # label = Qt.QLabel()

    def get_color():
        rect = button.rect()
        indent = 5

        pixmap = app.primaryScreen().grabWindow(button.winId(), rect.x(), rect.y() - indent, indent, indent)
        # label.setPixmap(pixmap)
        # label.setScaledContents(True)
        # label.resize(400, 400)
        # label.show()

        color = pixmap.toImage().pixelColor(0, 0)
        button.setStyleSheet('background-color: ' + color.name())

    button = Qt.QPushButton('Get')
    button.clicked.connect(get_color)
    button.resize(100, 100)
    button.show()

    app.exec()
```

Comment: Гениально! Сработало, большое спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

[Ссылка на ответ](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19368563/5909792):

```
QColor getWindowFrameColor() {
    // This is the only way to detect that a given color is supported
    HBRUSH brush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER);
    if (brush) {
        DWORD color = GetSysColor(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER);
        return QColor(GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color));
        // calling DeleteObject(brush) is unnecessary, but would be harmless
    }
    return QColor();
}
```

---

[Переписал](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/74001b902b02c0a49f39320188097856a48ccff5/pyqt5__winapi__get_color_window_frame_border.py) функцию для `PyQt5`:

```
from PyQt5 import Qt

COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER = 10

import ctypes
GetSysColorBrush = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSysColorBrush
GetSysColor = ctypes.windll.user32.GetSysColor


def GetRValue(value):
    return value & 0xff


def GetGValue(value):
    return value >> 8 & 0xff


def GetBValue(value):
    return value >> 16 & 0xff


def getWindowFrameColor():
    # This is the only way to detect that a given color is supported
    brush = GetSysColorBrush(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER)
    if brush:
        color = GetSysColor(COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER)
        return Qt.QColor(GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color))

    return Qt.QColor()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = Qt.QApplication([])

    def get_color():
        color = getWindowFrameColor()
        button.setStyleSheet('background-color: ' + color.name())

    button = Qt.QPushButton('Get')
    button.clicked.connect(get_color)
    button.resize(100, 100)
    button.show()

    app.exec()
```

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: К сожалению, возвращает только серый цвет (180, 180, 180)

Comment: Меняли цвет рамки? Я на скринах показывал пример

Comment: Да, но в любом случае возвращает серый

Comment: https://yadi.sk/i/WrMd5Zhw3Uhza6

Comment: возможно ли узнать цвет без использования PyQt?

Comment: PyQt только показывает цвет, сам цвет вы получаете в RGB: `GetRValue(color), GetGValue(color), GetBValue(color)`

Comment: Спасибо за помощь, но пока не находит активный цвет темы, буду дальше искать

Comment: Попробуйте вместо COLOR_ACTIVEBORDER использовать `COLOR_ACTIVECAPTION = 2`. Через тот же диалог персонализации ее можно задавать, но, такое ощущение, что заданная тема перекрывает цвет

Comment: @gil9rer  перепробовал уже все параметры от GetSysColor function - в основном цвета стандартные от черного до белого и синий для системных кнопок, но не намека на цвет темы, увы. Вероятно в какой-то другой функции, вот только в какой ?

Comment: Ну, у меня уже закончились идеи, дальше сами :)

Comment: Ок, как найду решение, распишу здесь